# Generating a random vector in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, signal-processing, fft

I'm trying to generate a random frequency spectrum and then use `ifft` to find the corresponding time domain vector.

I'm using the following code:

```
for i = 1:64
    randNum = (rand() + 1i * rand())/sqrt(2); % Needs to be normalized by sqrt(2)
    randFreq(i) = randNum;
end

randVec = ifft(randFreq);
```

Note that I'm aware of `mvnrnd`, however for technical reasons I **need** to use a `for` loop and generate each element individually. I also **need** to generate the random frequency spectrum and then use an inverse transform, I can't directly generate a random vector in the time domain.

If I plot the magnitude of the random vector (`plot(abs(randVec))`), I *always* get a graph of this form.

[image]

There's always a spike at `n=0` and all the other elements are significantly smaller in magnitude. I was hoping for some insight into why this was happening.

My question is *not* a duplicate of [Create random values in vector Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599336/create-random-values-in-vector-matlab), they are completely different questions that just happen to be on the same topic. I'm specifically asking about the behaviour of my `ifft`. It's not a duplicate of [spike in my inverse fourier transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932954/spike-in-my-inverse-fourier-transform) either. In that question, the spike could be caused by some idiosyncrasy of the data, however in my case the data is completely random.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create random values in vector Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599336/create-random-values-in-vector-matlab)

Comment: @galoget What? Did you read my question at all? They both ask about generating random vectors, but in completely different ways...

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I took a look at that question, but I don't think it's the same thing. In that question the spike could be caused by some idiosyncrasy with his data, however in my case the data is completely random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you generate the random values for the frequency components, they are not symmetrically distributed about zero. Specifically, the obtained real and imaginary parts have an ideal average of `.5/sqrt(2)`. The actual (sample) average will be close to that.

When you apply the IDFT, the average over all frequencies corresponds to the first sample in the time domain. To see this, set *n* = 0 in the [IDFT expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Completeness):

[image]

So you get a larger absolute value at that first sample because the average over frequency is larger than it "should".

Comment: Fair enough, how would I go about fixing this? (by making it symmetric about 0 I imagine?) Since the expected value operator is linear and `rand` has zero mean, I assumed `randNum` would also have zero mean.

Comment: _`rand` has zero mean_ No way

Comment: You are completely right! I thought `rand` sampled from a normal distribution! This fixed my problem, thank you so much.

Comment: @FarhadYusufali `randn` is normal (0 mean), `rand` is uniform (0.5 mean). You probably want `randn`